# React: generate selects based on dynamic data, where some selects could depend on another

Tags: reactjs

I want to build a system that allows the user to create custom categories for a Product. So, the categories is dynamic, I can't hard code the options, labels, etc...

When I generate a form page to create a new Product, I need to get the categories created by the user to render `<select>` and `<option>`. I don't have any static information about the number of categories, names, etc...

From start, my plan is to use this data structure to map the available categories:

```
categories = [
  //...
  {
    name: "project",
    label: "Project",
    required: true,
    options: [
      {
        label: "Project A",
        value: "02"
      },
      {
        label: "Project B",
        value: "01"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "subproject",
    label: "Sub Project",
    required: true,
    options: [
      {
        label: "Sub Project A-01",
        value: "021"
      },
      {
        label: "Sub Project A-02",
        value: "022"
      },
      {
        label: "Sub Project B-01",
        value: "011"
      },
    ]
  },
  //...
]
```

and kind of render the selects like this:

```
var selects = categories.map((category) => {
  var options = category.options.map((option) => {
    return <option value="{option.value}">{option.label}</option>;
  });
  
  return (
    <div>
      <label>{category.label}</label>
      <select name={category.name} required={category.required}>
        {options}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
});
```

Full demonstration: https://codesandbox.io/s/white-rain-8jg7uh?file=/src/App.js

The problem is when I need to set one select to depend on another select value, for example:

- show only `Sub Project A-01` and `Sub Project A-02` when `Project A` is selected
- show only `Sub Project B-01` when `Project B` is selected.

What is the best way to organize the data structure and render that in React?
Or there is a better way to allow the user to create custom categories with custom values?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you have as many subprojects as you want ? Or is it always two ?

Comment: I can have any number of categories, and any category can have any number of options

Answer (score 0):

To filter Sub Projects by a selected Project, you have to *save* the selected project, when user select it. There is a [React.useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook for that, something like this in your `App`:

```
const [project, setProject] = React.useState('');
```

To change the project, you have to handle the `onChange` event on the `<select>`, and call `setProject` with a selected value:

```
<select
  name={category.name}
  required={category.required}
  onChange={event => setProject(event.target.value)}
>/* some options */</select>
```

So, when a user select any project from this select, the value appears in the `project` variable. And then you can *filter* Sub Projects by *selected* (or saved) Project (`project` variable):

```
/* As I see, you make the value of a subproject to starts with a project value
So the function returns true if the subproject belongs to project */
function belongsTo(subprojectValue, projectValue) {
  return subprojectValue.startsWith(projectValue);
}

const availableSubprojects = categories[1].options.filter((option) => {
  return project !== '' && belongsTo(option.value, project);
});
```

For making the code more readable, I prefer to extract the `select` rendering into the `Select` component.

With your data structure, the app may looks like this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-wood-hn0opq